# Aligning Ir images and RGB images

Tags: image-processing, image-registration

I was wondering if given a picture from a Raspberry Pi NoIr camera and a Raspberry Pi RGB camera, how can the two images be aligned. From what I understand the NoIR camera when used with the blue filter stores near IR values in the Red band. So how could the RGB image and the NoIR image be aligned? Can the IR band of the image be aligned with indiv